# Can't see the "sources" folder on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

[When I open a win32 console application empty project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpQMZ.png)

Suddenly I have no folders on the side, including the sources folder where I should add a new cpp file. what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the Solution Explorer view to handle my sources. Isn't it just a case of you closing the Solution Explorer view?

If that's the case, click on View -> Solution Explorer.

[image: This is what it looks like in Visual Studio 2015 Community]